# Triple integral over an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ be the solid ellipsoid $E = ${$(x,y,z)$ | $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} \le 1$} where $a > 0,\: b > 0,\: c > 0$

Evaluate $\int\int \int xyz\: dxdydz$ over:

a. the whole ellipsoid

b. that part of it in the first quadrant, $x \ge 0,\: y \ge 0,\: z \ge 0$

So for the first part, I made the change of variables $u = \frac{x}{a}$, $v = \frac{y}{b}$, $w = \frac{z}{c}$. The ellipse became a sphere. I then made another change of variables into spherical coordinates. I found that the integral evaluated to $$\frac{-2\pi*a^2b^2c^2}{9}$$

Now I am not sure about part b.) Since I change the ellipsoid into a unit sphere, do I just change the bounds to what they are in the first quadrant (ie, theta ranges from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of 0 to $2\pi$), then integrate the same way I did in a.)?

(Also, if someone could check my answer for a.) that would be great. I have an exam coming and I'm weak in this area. Thanks!)

Comment: Something to bear in mind for your answer in $(a)$: In the first orthant (the one you compute in $(b)$, all three variables are positive and so the product is positive. If you go to the next adjacent orthants, the products are negative. Repeating this, you end up with four positive orthants and four negative orthants. What does this suggest about the value of the integral in $(a)$?

Comment: Okay, I see why it should be 0. I can't figure out what I did wrong though. After my u,v,w substitution, I got the triple integral of ((au)(bv)(cw) * abc) over the unit ball. I then changed u, v, and w to spherical coordinates (such as u = $\rho sin \phi cos \theta$, with the bounds $\rho$ from 0 to 1, $\phi$ from 0 to pi, and theta from 0 to 2pi. Is that the wrong method?

Comment: That all seems correct. But it should be the case that the angular integration yields zero. (Both $\theta$ and $\phi$ integrals do so separately, owing to the high degree of symmetry of the problem.) So I'd examine that part of it more carefully.

Comment: I am interested to see what comes out. I tried finding the mass moment of inertia of a thin spherical ellipsoid shell (triple integral also) and failed.

Answer (score 2):

You should have gotten $0$ as the answer for the first part. Since $xyz$ is odd w.r.t. $x$ and the ellipsoid is symmetric about the plane $x = 0$, the integral over the whole ellipsoid is $0$. Note this argument can also be used if the integrand is odd w.r.t. $y$ or $z$ and the region is symmetric about the planes $y = 0$ to $z = 0$ respectively.

For the second part, note that $xyz > 0$ over the part of the ellipsoid in the first **octant**, so the integral should evaluate to something positive.

Be sure to double check your bounds. The first octant has bounds of $0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 \le \phi \le \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.